# Linkage between homotopy equivalence and identification of algorithms

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, computability-theory, hodge-theory

I vaguely recall that someone says there is linkage  between homotopy equivalence and identification of algorithms which may be isomorphic or morphism  or something like that,the algorithm may be regard as path,and may be interpreted in geometry.It is a new approach to computational theory.Could any one give me any reference,or explanation?Thanks a lot

Comment: this is called "univalent foundations of mathematics", see e.g. http://homotopytypetheory.org/

Comment: Thank you very much.It is much more helpful than down vote by someone else